# how to change headers data

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

i have the following class

```
class AssetTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self,filename=''):
        super(AssetTableModel,self).__init__()
        self.fileName=filename
        self.dirty = False
        self.assets = []
        self.setHeaderData(0,QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,QtCore.QVariant('moayyad'),QtCore.Qt.EditRole)
```

and i need to change the **headers of the columns or the rows** ,i used  ( `self.setHeaderdata()`)
but its not working ,i have a table that consists of 2 columns and 2 rows only. is there any other function that changes headers ??.

please help
thanx in adnvance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers of the columns or the rows will be obtained from your model by the view.  The function used to obtain the header data is `virtual QVariant headerData ( int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const` ([C++ documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qabstractitemmodel.html#headerData)).  In order to change the headers shown, you should be able to override this function and return the information you want shown for the proper section/orientation.  You might want to check the various roles that you can also have requested.